# Call php function from Objective c

Tags: php, objective-c

Can I call a php function in a web server from Objective-c? I need to call this function and in case pass the variables. 
Thanks.

Comment: so you're trying to call a web service (written in PHP) from an iOS app ?

Comment: I have a question. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, I must call a web server from an iOS app.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I have a web server written in php that interacts with electronic hardware and I must control these from the iPhone

Comment: @Kerberos you need to ask a better question - i.e. "how do I send a CGI POST or GET from an iOS application" ?  The fact that the server side is PHP is irrelevant Chances are, that's already been answered here, though!

Comment: You are right but I don't know English well. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can just make get request with the parameters to the server, the server side will get the parameters with `$_GET` then process it.